# How are dihedral groups $D_1$ and $D_2$ defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I'm a beginner here so I'd really appreciate an answer in simple English. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) defines Dihedral groups as a collection of rotational isometries $r, r^2, \ldots, r^n=e$ and reflection isometries $s, sr, sr^2, \ldots, sr^{n-1}$ satisfying $(sr)^2 =e$ of $n-$gon.

How are the smaller Dihedral groups, $D_1$ and $D_2$ defined and "what" are they rotational and reflection isometries of? Wikipedia directly starts mentioning relations like $D_1$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2= \mathbb{Z} /2\mathbb{Z}$ and $D_2$ is Klein group but what is $D_1$ and $D_2$, in the first place.

How do I view $D_1$ and $D_2$ as symmetries of $1-$gon and $2-$gon respectively? How does one picture a $1$ and $2$ sided polygon? Can anyone walk me through it?

[MSE question 470570](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/470570/552998) is another related question but the OP and the person answering seem to already agree on what a $1-$gon is. I don't understand that $1−$gon or $2−$gon. A polygon is defined as closed plane figure with edges and vertices. What are edges and vertices in this case? What is a reflection here? What is a rotation? What do the elements in $D_1$ and $D_2$ look like?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470570/the-small-dihedral-groups-d-1-and-d-2

Comment: I think, in view of the linked question, you should re-write your question to focus on it. (Basically, your edited-in final paragraph makes much of the first 3 irrelevant.)

Comment: @user1729 Thanks for the input. I guess I will.

Answer (score 1):

To recycle part of the answer linked:
[image: Image from M. Artin's book Algebra containing a representation of a 1-gon and a 2-gon. The 1-gon is represented as an oval-shape loop from a point on its right to the point itself. The 2-gon is represented as a 2 dimensional rugby ball shape with two points along the x-axis and a 'hill' and 'trough' line connecting the two points.]

The following might help your intuition with regard to some of your questions, you've asked quite a number of them.

The symmetry of the 1-gon is pretty simple as there is "no" rotation and we only have to understand a single reflection, which assuming the 1-gon is as above to begin would be this:

[image: The 1-gon is as before, except the single point is now to the left of the loop. This illustrates a reflection through the y-axis.]

To show the symmetries of the 2-gon, we start with a coloured version of the 2-gon above to help us distinguish between the reflection and the rotation:

[image: The 2-gon is as before but with added colours: the 'hill' is now coloured red, the 'trough' is now coloured green, the left point is yellow, and the right point is blue.]

Now the rotation by $\pi$ radians, r, looks like this:

[image: The 2-gon now has a green hill, red trough, blue point to the right, and yellow point to the left, i.e., the colours of the lines and the points have switched places from the original. This illustrates a rotation by pi radians or 180 degrees.]

Next, the reflection through the vertical axis, s, looks like this:

[image: The 2-gon now has a red hill and a green trough, a blue point to the left and a yellow point to the right, i.e., only the colours of the points have switched places from the original. This illustrates a reflection through the vertical axis.]

Finally, reflection followed by rotation, or rotation followed by reflection looks like this. Note that this is equivalent to reflection through the horizontal axis which therefore gives us $(sr)^2 = e$ as required:

[image: The 2-gon now has a green hill and a red trough, with a yellow point to the left and a blue point to the right, i.e., only the colours of the lines have switched places. This illustrates composition of a rotation and a reflection (in whichever order).]

As I said, this answer is intended just to help with intuition/visualisation, so don't take it as Gospel.