# How to visualise $1$-gon and $2$-gon for the dihedral groups $D_1$ and $D_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polygons, dihedral-groups

For $n≥3$, the Dihedral groups may be defined as a collection of rotational isometries $r, r^2, \ldots, r^n=e$ and reflection isometries $s, sr, sr^2, \ldots, sr^{n-1}$ satisfying $(sr)^2 =e$ of $n-$gon.

But how does one make sense of smaller dihedral groups $D_1$ and $D_2$, in that what is a $1$-gon or $2$-gon.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/470570/552998) is a related question but I don't understand how that $1$-gon or $2$-gon is drawn. As I understand it, a polygon is defined as closed plane figure with "edges" and "vertices". What are the edges and vertices in this case? And hence what would a rotation or reflection look like here? Is there any intuition to it?

I'm new to Dihedral groups so I'd really appreciate an answer in simple English.

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: The rotations and reflections are all considered to be acting on the plane--the dihedral group is in essence the set of all isometric transformations of the plane that leave an  $n$-gon unchanged. In this way, $\text{Dih}_{2}$ is just the set of transformations preserving a line segment. I don't know how to understand $\text{Dih}_{1}$ in this way, though.

Comment: I do not think that this should be downvoted, but it is difficult to visualize so small groups in the same way it is done for $D_n$ with $n\ge 3$. $D_1$ is the cyclic group with $2$ elements, hence the graph would just be two points that are adjacent (it makes no sense to rotate or mirror a point). And $D_2$ is the Klein-four-group. No idea how this can be visualized as desired.

Comment: You should not [delete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302726/how-are-dihedral-groups-d-1-and-d-2-defined) your old question about it, but rather edit it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes sorry, someone told me I should rewrite it because I guess the question was not clear. I figured I should write a new question make it as clear as possible. Of course, I could've editted it but it didn't click me at the time.

Comment: No problem. But this may be a reason that some users think it is one of the repeated posts, where the comments and solutions hints are just ignored and deleted, and the question is reposted.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ah yes, of course. Don't worry. I took that into consideration before deleting the question because nobody would want their answers or comments that they have spent time on to write, to be deleted. But it wasn't answered, there were only two comments, none of which had anything to do with my question.

Comment: The point being made is that you should not do what you did. It is a misuse of the site, it causes confusion, at best, and causes annoyance. Do not delete and repost.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, I understand. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case of $D_2$ can be reasonably done "geometrically" following the usual description of $D_n$ as the "rigid motions of the regular $n$-gon", provided you are okay with degenerate geometrical objects.

There regular $n$-gon consists of $n$ vertices, numbered $1$ through $n$, with edges going from $v_1$ to $v_2$, from $v_2$ to $v_3$, and so on, until we get to an edge from $v_{n-1}$ to $v_n$, and one from $v_n$ to $v_1$. Thus, among other things the regular $n$-gon has $n$ vertices and $n$ edges. We may want to think of the edges as having "direction", which rigid motions may preserve (when they are rotations) or reverse (when they are reflections)

What would be the "regular $2$-gon", then? Well, it consists of two vertices, $v_1$ and $v_2$, an edge from $v_1$ to $v_2$, and an edge from $v_2$ to $v_1$. It's important to note, however, that *they are not the same edge*: they don't have the same direction, and we need to consider them as two different edges, so that we keep the same pattern of $2$ vertices and $2$ edges. You could think of them as two edges superimposed on one another, or as two edges infinitesimally close to one another. The picture in your link shows them as "curved" segments to emphasize that they are two different edges.

What are the rigid motions of this geometric object? You can fix the two vertices and exchange the two edges (a "reflection"); or you can exchange the two vertices and fix the two edges (a "reflection" again); or you can "rotate" by exchanging the two vertices and the two edges. A little bit of work will show that you get the group $\langle \rho,\sigma\mid \rho^2=\sigma^2=1,\ \sigma\rho=\rho\sigma\rangle$, which fits perfectly into the dihedral framework once you note that $\rho\sigma$ is the same as $\rho^{-1}\sigma$, in the presence of the relation $\rho^2=1$. Here, $\sigma$ is the first reflection I described, and $\rho$ is the rotation. This presentation gives the Klein $4$-group, as expected.

Following the same idea, what would be a regular $1$-gon? It would consists of exactly one vertex $v_1$, and exactly one edge going from $v_1$ to $v_1$; pictorially that would just look like a point, perhaps with an infinitesimally small "loop" around it. That's the picture you have in your link, only greatly magnified to show the "loop".

What are the rigid motions here? Well, $v_1$ must go to $v_1$. But if you think of the edge as having a "direction", then you can either keep its direction (the "rotation") or you can "reverse" it (the "reflection"). It's a conceit or fiction, but one that fits into the general dihedral framework again, so it is worth being fictional so that you get the group
$$D_1 = \langle \rho,\sigma\mid \rho^1=\sigma^2=1,\quad \sigma\rho=\rho^{-1}\sigma\rangle,$$
which is a somewhat over-complicated way of presenting the cyclic group of order $2$.

Comment: Thanks Arturo, I suppose it will take some time for me "internalize" this way of looking at $D_1$ and $D_2$, if that makes any sense. In any case, would you happen to know some book or any text that talks about $D_1$ and $D_2$ aside from the one in my question. I couldn't find anything on the internet about the small Dihedral groups, perhaps because they're not very interesting to look at like that. Maybe it's just easier on the eyes to look at $D_1$ as $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $D_2$ as Klein group. In any case, I'm curious. Any book/text suggestions you can point me to?

Comment: @William: $D_1$ and $D_2$ are "degenerate examples" of dihedral groups. They are very different from the rest of the dihedral groups (for example, "$D_n$ is not abelian...except $n=1,2$"; "$Z(D_n)$ is trivial if $n$ is odd (except $n=1$), and cyclic of order $2$ if $n$ is even (except $n=2$)"; "$D_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$... except for $n=1$ and $n=2$." etc. So it actually makes more sense to **omit** $D_1$ and $D_2$ than include them, because if you include them then you end up having to mention them as exceptional pretty much each and every time you try to say something general.

Comment: @William: I mean, it's kinda nice to see you could extend the definition to $n=1$ and $2$, but in practice it's just much better *not* to include them in the family. Because of that, you aren't going to find any books that just treat them as generic dihedral groups. They just stick out like sore thumbs in the family, so it's better to excommunicate them from the family of dihedral groups.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. If that is the norm then I suppose it can't be helped. I'm self-teaching myself group theory so I do not know how dihedral groups are actually introduced to students but if it's introduced as $D_n, n ≥3$ then that makes life easy. Thanks Arturo, always a big help.

Comment: @William: Indeed, that is standard. E.g., Hungerford: "Another important subgroup of $S_n$ ($n\geq 3$) is the subgroup $D_n$..."  Robinson: "Let $X$ be the regular polygon with $n$ edges ($n\geq 3$)..."